# How to convert android TextToSpeech.getAvailableLanguages() to a string[]

Tags: android, godot

I know nothing about Java or android development. I use Godot and I'm trying to add Android Text-to-speech functionality to my app. I have it working, but want to know what Languages the user has for tts.

I tried this:

```
public String[] language_available() {
    Set<Locale> set = tts.getAvailableLanguages();
        String[] myArray = new String[set.size()];
        set.toArray(myArray);
        return myArray;
    }
```

but the app crashes. I checked adb logcat and it says:

"java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.util.Locale cannot be stored in an array of type java.lang.String[]"

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Elements of your array are not of String type, and that's why you get the error.

Comment: How am I able to see what the elements are then? can I convert the elements to string? I thought it was just "Locale.US" for example